# Font attribute (NSFontAttributeName) not applied to attributed string

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to apply two attributes to a string, one for kerning (`NSKernAttributeName`) and one for the font (`NSFontAttributeName`). Although I've checked and rechecked 1000 times, I can only get the kerning attribute to be applied to the string. Here's my setup:

```
    let runAtTitle = "RUN AT"
    var attRunAt = NSMutableAttributedString(string: runAtTitle)

    let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 76.0)!
    let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: font, NSKernAttributeName: -3.0]
    attRunAt.addAttributes(attrs, range: NSMakeRange(0, attRunAt.length))

    runAtLabel.attributedText = attRunAt
```

When I build the app, the kerning is applied to my string, but the font is not. It uses the default 12pt Helvetica. Please tell me I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your code in Playground and it works fine. Most likely you are setting the `text` attribute of the label after setting the `attributedText`. That will revert the string to the normal label string with its attributes, or perhaps for some strange reason keep the kern attribute.

Here is what I get with your code:

[image]

and after adding

```
label.text = "RUN AT"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Mundi. I tried it in a playground and also got it to work, so I think you're right. The issue must be somewhere else.